# How to make the max/min element of an array to 0? or remove them from the array

Tags: java, arrays

Say I enter values 1-10 in the array and when I try to run the code and print the values of my array, the max value of the element is still 10.0, how can I make that value to 0.0 or completely remove it from my array?
btw, I'm new to java and programming.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exer20 {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double[] judges = new double[10];

for(int a=0; a < judges.length; a++){
    judges[a] = input.nextDouble();
}

double max = judges[0];
double maxIndex = 0;
double min = judges[0];

for(int x = 0; x < judges.length; x++){
    if(judges[x] > max)
        max = judges[x];
        maxIndex = x;

}
maxIndex = 0.0;
max = 0.0;

for(double b:judges)
    System.out.println(b);


}

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to find the max element in an array, and set it to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
max = 0.0;
```

to

```
judges[maxIndex] = 0.0
```

when you set primitive types they are copied by value. So when you change max it doesn't affect the judges array. You have to manipulate the array directly.

Comment: Hey it worked! But I needed to change the "double maxIndex = 0" to "int maxIndex = 0" because I got the error, "type mismatch cannot convert double to int" when my maxIndex is double, I don't understand why.

Comment: That is because you are using it to index an array. Arrays only allow integer indices. So when you do judges[maxIndex] you have to make sure maxIndex is an integer or it will throw that error.

Comment: Oh, I now fully understand! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As your question already states that you are entering the values in your array of type double from 1-10 in sorted order,hence the minimum value in the array will be at 0th location and maximum value in array will be at last location, hence to make them 0 use the following code snippet:

```
 judges[0]=0.0; //setting minimum to 0

 judges[judges.length-1]=0.0; //setting maximum to 0
```

In case your array is not sorted,then make them in sorted order using any of sorting logic and apply the above given code snippet,as sorting of array will help to easily locate minimum and maximum value in array.